Weaknesses of the alternative RSA-like algorithm
Disclaimer: it is a purely out-of-curiosity question. We discussed this implementation with a friend and could not find any breaches, but I have a gut feeling that there might be some.
Consider a world where Fermat's little theorem ($a^p \equiv a \mod p$ for prime $p$) is known but Euler's theorem ($a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ for general $n$) is not. Then one could come up with the following encryption algorithm. Let us do all exponentiations over modulo $p$. Public and private exponents are mutual inverses modulo $p - 1$. However, in this case it would be trivial to deduce $d$ given $e$, so we disguise our modulus by multiplying it by some other (mostly irrelevant) prime $q$. All computations will be performed modulo $pq$ by both parties, but the owner of the private key will take the result modulo $p$ at the end.
Private key:

$p$, $q$ — two $k$-bit primes
$0 < d < p - 1$ — private exponent

Public key:

$m = pq$
$e$ — public exponent s.t. $de \equiv 1 \mod p - 1$ (note the difference from the classical RSA)

Encryption: given $x < 2^k$, return $y = x^e \mod m$.
Decryption: given $y < pq$, take $\hat{x} = y^d \mod pq$ and $x = \hat{x} \mod p$. Since $x < p$ and $de \equiv 1 \mod p - 1$, it follows $((y^e)^d \mod p) = x$.
I see two possible downsides of this algorithm, compared with classical RSA.

One must work with $2k$-bit numbers for $k$-bit message, so encryption is slower for same key strength.
This scheme does not work for digital signature: given $y = x^d \mod pq$, public key owner cannot validate that $(y^d)^e$ equals $x$ modulo $p$ since $p$ is unknown.

However, are there any security issues with encryption scheme? It seems very unlikely to know anything about modulus factorization given only the public exponent but it seems that I'm missing something very obvious.

One issue with this scheme is that (as written) it is vulnerable to a chosen ciphertext attack. That is, an adversary who can ask the owner of a private key to decrypt some ciphertexts of their choice can recover the private key. In fact, you probably only need a single chosen ciphertext (most of the time).
The idea is as follows. The adversary takes some $p < x < m$ and computes $y = x^e \bmod m$. The adversary then asks for the decryption of $y$; the owner of the key computes an $x' < p$ by the above scheme. Now, we are guaranteed $x$ is congruent to $x'$ modulo $p$, so by computing $\mathrm{gcd}(x' - x, m)$, the adversary is very likely to recover $p$ (and hence the rest of the private key).
I think you can fix this specific vulnerability by having the decryptor check that $(x')^e \bmod m$ is actually equal to $y$ (and returning a decryption error otherwise). It's possible that this fix could introduce some other issues though -- I have not thought about this carefully.
